# elif invalid syntax (<string, line 8>) pylint(syntax-error)

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to make a basic area calculator just to get my bearings with Python but I keep coming upon this syntax error

I've tried playing with the indentation and asking a friend of mine who's familiar with js.

```
4 if option == 'C' or option == 'c':
5   radius = float(raw_input('Enter radius: '))
6   area = 3.14159 * radius**2
7 print 'Area: %f' % area
8 elif option == 'T' or option == 't':
9   base = float(raw_input("Enter base: "))
10  height = float(raw_input("Enter height: "))
11   areaT = .5 * base * height
12      print 'Area: %f' % areaT
```

I expected the program to run without a problem but I continually get this error

Comment: You've got an unindented `print` statement that leaves the `elif` without an `if`

Comment: Indentation needs to be correct in Python. You have print statement intruding between the `if` statement and the `elif` statement. Then lower down your indentation becomes seemingly arbitrary.

Comment: Think about line 7: how does Python know that it belongs to the body of the `if` statement, rather than marking the end of the `if` statement? And if the `if` statement is finished, what is `elif` attached to?

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that your code is properly indented:

```
if option == 'C' or option == 'c':
    radius = float(raw_input('Enter radius: '))
    area = 3.14159 * radius**2
    print 'Area: %f' % area
elif option == 'T' or option == 't':
    base = float(raw_input("Enter base: "))
    height = float(raw_input("Enter height: "))
    areaT = .5 * base * height
    print 'Area: %f' % areaT
```

Answer (score 0):

Just correcting your indentation of the code will make your code work

```
option = raw_input()
if option == 'C' or option == 'c':
    radius = float(raw_input('Enter radius: '))
    area = 3.14159 * radius**2
    print 'Area: %f' % area

elif option == 'T' or option == 't':
    base = float(raw_input("Enter base: "))
    height = float(raw_input("Enter height: "))
    areaT = .5 * base * height
    print 'Area: %f' % areaT
```